# Problem reading XML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

My Ruby script is supposed to read in an XML doc from a URL and check it for well-formedness, returning any errors.  I have a sample bad XML document hosted with the following text (from the [Nokogiri tutorial](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/ensuring_well_formed_markup.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <root>
    <open>foo
      <closed>bar</closed>
  </root>
```

My test script is as follows (url refers to the above xml file hosted on my personal server):

```
require 'nokogiri'

document = Nokogiri::XML(url) 

puts document
puts document.errors
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

Why is it only capturing the first line of the XML file?  It does this with even with known good XML files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too sure what code you are using to actually output the contents of the XML. I only see error printing code. However, I have posted some sample code to effectively move through XML with Nokogiri below:

```
<item>
  Something
</item> 
<item>
  Else
</item>

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
set = doc.xpath('//item')
set.each {|item| puts item.to_s}
  #=> Something
  #=> Else
```

In general, the tutorial [here](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) should help you.

Comment: I think my problem seems to be related to the line where it reads the XML file into a document.  I have yet to find a single example online where: doc = Nokogiri::XML(url) works. Every sample looks like: @doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("shows.xml")).

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me know if there is something not clear.

Comment: @providence, yes I tried requiring that. Serabe made it clear that my syntax was incorrect, but I haven't yet figured out how to get it to parse the contents of the provided url.

Comment: Shoot sorry, that line should be Nokogiri::XML(open(url)). I have corrected my example. You can see it in context here: https://github.com/jprovidence/Arrogance/blob/rails/lib/arrogance/tools.rb

Answer (score 5):

It is trying to parse the url, not its content. Please, take into account that first parameter to `Nokogiri::XML` must be a string containing the document or an `IO` object since it is just a shortcut to `Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse` as stated [here](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/xml.rb#L31).

**EDIT:** For reading from an uri

```
require 'open-uri'
open(uri).read
```

Comment: OK, I understand that now. How then do I parse the contents when all I have is the URL?

Comment: Updated! It is easy to open an uri with 'open-uri'.

Comment: I ended up using providence's line doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url)), but thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the xml from a Nokogiri xml already, then make sure you use '.to_s' before passing it to the XML function.

for example,
  xml = Nokogiri::XML(existing_nokogiri_xml_doc.to_s)